# Jobs Status Window disappear after job finished

Tags: scheduler-job

When Job status is finished, modal window disappear and I can't see messages from Job.Status.Messages, is there any way to hold window ?
Job is triggered by Command.

```
var jobOption = new JobOptions(CommandTitle, CommandCategory, Client.Site.Name, this, nameof(Action), new object[] { args })
            {
                ContextUser = Context.User,
                ClientLanguage = Context.Language
            };

            var job = JobManager.Start(jobOption);
            var longRunningOption = new LongRunningOptions(job.Handle.ToString())
            {
                Title = CommandTitle,
                Icon = string.Empty
            };

            job.Finished += OnJob_FinishedFaildMessage;

            handleString = job.Handle.ToString();

            longRunningOption.ShowModal(true);
            args.WaitForPostBack();
```

If is set e.Job.Status.State to JobState.Unknown in OnJob_FinishedFaildMessage, modal window not disapper.

Comment: Can you be more specific? How do you trigger the job?